# Regex: Find and show only the string between FIRST-PART and SECOND-PART of the text

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this text, from many other html with the same format and links, only the text is different. I want to extract this part of the text: "the ideal hypostasis of a vast expanse". Basicaly, after find this text with regex, I need to see that words in the search results.

```
...<br><br>The message that an artist emphasizes in his personal work is &nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/zh/how-are-you.html">the ideal hypostasis of a vast expanse<img src="ru.jpg"</a> that includes the space between himself and the components of the surrounding world.<en>
```

So, I made a regex, with this formula `FIRST-PART.*?SECOND-PART`

FIND: `&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/zh/how-are-you.html">.*?<img src="ru.jpg"</a>`

The problem of my regex, is that the result it show me all the line, but I need to show me only the text: `the ideal hypostasis of a vast expanse`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?s)(?<=FIRST-PART).*?(?=SECOND-PART)`

**OR**

- Find what: `(?s)(?<=FIRST-PART)\K(.*?)(?=SECOND-PART)|\1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*

In your case, FIND HIS:

`(?s)(?<=&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/zh/how-are-you.html">).*?(?=<img src="ru.jpg"</a>)`

Comment: work. for future interests, your solution here: https://regex101.com/r/Qw55c3/1

Comment: nope, is no very good, because if I search in ALL FILES (in a folder with many html files) I will not get as the result only that text between FIRST-PART and SECOND-PART...

Comment: Maybe @Toto has another better idea :)